# How to partially display Navigation Drawer

Tags: navigation-drawer, android

Normally in Navigation Drawer when we click on the top left corner icon the Navigation drawer will be opened as shown in the screen1.

I need to display Navigation drawer partially as shown in the below screen 2 while the screen(Activity) is launched initially without firing any event.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks
Ravi

[image: Screen 1 This is the normal functionality when we click on the Navigation button on the top left corner of the screen]

[image: Screen 2 I need to display Navigation drawer like this initially]

Comment: You mean Change the width of the Navigation drawer? Or what do you mean by not firing any `Event`?

Comment: @Mike  I need to show navigation drawer partially when I launch the screen.

Comment: Just Change the width after instantiate the NavigationDrawer in `onCreate` and set state to `open`!

Comment: I know you can find workarounds as suggested by fellow programmers. But I just for curiosity, why do you wanna do this? :)

Answer (score 0):

set the width for ListView dynamically...

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.top_sectionlist);

int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2;
DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mDrawerList.getLayoutParams();
params.width = width;
mDrawerList.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit for your reply. I tried your code but am not able to make Navigation drawer partially visible initially.

Comment: Have you tried it with DrawerListener in onDrawerSlide method?

Comment: Hey another option is you can give android:layout_marginLeft="200dp" to your left layout.